# How to Xor a String with a key and store in a file to decrypt later and use it?

Tags: java, encryption

I have researched a lot on this question and finally understood this, that encrypting and decryption using just XOR is not a suggested way of encryption but as it is an academic question I have to do it.

In my scenario I have to save java objects(space delimited strings with xor encryption by a key of our choice) in a file(.txt file) line by line and retrieve them later on if needed. So saving a xor string in a file is not a problem but while decrpytion its getting truncated. Below is a sample similar code which I have implemented for my project.

```
public class TestingXor {
    private static String XorString(String input){
        String key = "computing";
        Charset charSet = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        byte[] inputBytes = input.getBytes(charSet);
        byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes(charSet);
        for(int i=0;i<inputBytes.length;i++){
            inputBytes[i] = (byte)(inputBytes[i] ^ keyBytes[i%keyBytes.length]);
        }
        return (new String(inputBytes,charSet));
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            File testFile = new     File("addressBook.txt");
            Scanner scanObj = new Scanner(testFile);
            String testString = "asd asdasd 07/08/2015 asdasdasd 198546125";
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(testFile));
            writer.write(XorString(testString));
            writer.close();
            System.out.println(XorString(scanObj.nextLine()));          
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

The above code returns "asd as" where as I need the whole string .If I am not saving the file I am able to encrypt and decrypt properly, but If I am saving the string to a file and retrieving the string from the file and decrypting it does'nt work. I think it is related to saving of the string(\0 getting saved in the middle of the line) but what is the work around this. I dont know the length of the string when I am reading from a file. If this question is already answered you can redirect me to that question.

Comment: You need to read the whole file, not a line or even multiple lines, because after XORing you don't have text at all; there are numerous dupes but some are for text so I recommend http://stackoverflow.com/a/326440/2868801 . Also you operate on bytes which won't work for characters that require more than one byte in UTF-8, so in fact your code will work only on ASCII, but your example data is ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you `XorString` method can return String that contain newlines or other other line separator characters (basically `\r\n\u2028\u2029\u0085` and the end of the file. Bad luck for you, your test generated multiple '\r' which makes the `Scanner` stop looking for the rest of the string.

One way to get away from this is to use some kind of escaping mechanisms. For example, `Properties` provide such a mechanism, but feel free to implement your own.

Small example:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Properties;

public class TestingXor {
    private static String xorString(String input) {
        String key = "computing";
        Charset charSet = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        byte[] inputBytes = input.getBytes(charSet);
        byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes(charSet);
        for (int i = 0; i < inputBytes.length; i++) {
            inputBytes[i] = (byte) (inputBytes[i] ^ keyBytes[i % keyBytes.length]);
        }
        return new String(inputBytes, charSet);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File testFile = new File("addressBook.txt");
        store(testFile);
        load(testFile);
    }

    private static void load(File file) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        try (InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));) {
            props.load(in);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < props.size() + 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(xorString(props.getProperty("entry-" + i)));
        }
    }

    private static void store(File file) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        String testString = "asd asdasd 07/08/2015 asdasdasd 198546125";
        props.put("entry-1", xorString(testString));
        try (OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));) {
            props.store(out, "Some comment");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So is there any other way to retrieve string line by line from a text file apart from scanner or Is there any other format which I need to change my string to save in a file?

Comment: @user3324848 Yes, you need to use some kind of escape mechanisms that avoids new lines for example. Find in my answer, a use of the Properties class that internally performs something similar.